# How to extract image metadata Dart/Flutter

Tags: image, flutter, dart, metadata

I am new to dart/flutter and I am trying to extract metadata from images. I am using [flutter_image_gallery](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_image_gallery) plugin to get all images on the device and it works fine but on the plugin page, it says it can get metadata and Thumbnail but I can't figure it out how to extract that.

Answer (score 1):

[exif](https://pub.dev/packages/exif) plugin can be used to read the metadata of images. To use, read the image file using `File.readAsBytesSync()` then use `readExifFromBytes()`.

```dart
final fileBytes = File(imagePath).readAsBytesSync();
final data = await readExifFromBytes(fileBytes);
```